# C++ Library: What is the Most Efficient Library that Factorizes a Polynomial?

Tags: c++, libraries, polynomials

I need to know what library is the fastest one that can factorize a polynomial of large degree whose coefficients are big integers.

I have tried NTL library to factorize a monic polynomial but it is not efficient.

Comment: Have you tried [GiNaC](http://www.ginac.de/)?

Comment: [FLINT](http://www.flintlib.org/index.html)?